# Why is the name 'Batman' avoided in the Dawn of Justice?

Tags: character, dc-extended-universe, batman-v-superman-dawn-of-justice

Strangely the name 'Batman' is almost never mentioned in *Batman v Superman: Dawn of Justice* (except in the title). The characters use other names such as 'The dark one' or so when they are talking about him.

Why is this happening? Is it because of copyright problems?

Comment: It *does* appear, though. Perry White [says](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2975590/quotes) "Nobody cares about Clark Kent taking on the Batman". And I'm pretty sure it appears a couple of times in [writing](http://www.cinemablend.com/images/news/72529/_1436646336.jpg).

Comment: I surely didn't notice it. If it does indeed I will delete the question

Comment: Or you could just ask why it *almost never* appears, instead.

Comment: @Walt Luckily I say 'avoided' in my question title although I thought it was never mentioned. I completely missed the Perry White line. I'm pretty sure though, that characters avoid to say the word 'Batman'

Comment: I added the 'almost', just in case. Is that OK?

Comment: I remember Lex Luthor says "Bat from Gotham" at one point as well.. I think this is probably a coincidence, but it would be interesting to know if there was any reasoning.

Comment: They're trying to avoid campy use of Superhero names, and are going for a darker, grittier, edgier approach. Saying "the bat" rather than "batman" seems more realistic to come out of an adult's mouth, when speaking cynically or critically about the superhero.

Comment: they used just "the Bat" rather than calling him "The Batman", I noticed that, could be wrong though

Answer (score 1):

As I see, being much darker tone unlike other superhero movies(Ex:Avengers), They used rough impression that Batman illustrates himself in. rather than being just a guy dressed as bat who fights crime, BvS Batman is rather iconic character. He is rude, fearless and merciless. Calling him The Bat illustrates that Batman is more iconic figure than mere human. That shows some kind of fear and respect for what he do. Also calling him "The Bat" sound like more realistic conversation among adults, rather than calling him "The Batman"

Answer (score 1):

This version of Batman was more strictly based on Frank Miller and Bill Finger's versions of the character.  Bob Kane, the other co-creator, had a huge falling out with Finger at some point and refused to even concede that Finger was a co-creator and provided most of Batman's early crimefighting capabilities.  In fact, it's the first time Finger has officially been credited as a co-creator in a Batman film.  When the character was first introduced in Detective Comics #27 (May 1939), he was referred to as "The Bat-Man".  Most of the time he's simply referred to as "The Bat" in BvS, which is just a shortened version of "The Bat-Man".

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so the base theme of BvS was a dark one. Few points that I would like to put some light on -

- Superman first appeared from the sky and created mass havoc while fighting Zod and his army.
- Superman made so much destruction that people started taking him as a threat more than a hero or anything.
- There was havoc everywhere, police and government not having the peace they want.

Now,

- Batman doesn't believe in Superman, right from the time he saw his *casually* demolishing buildings. It is shown multiple times that Bruce believes that Clark shouldn't be trusted; that me might as well be our enemy.
- Bruce doesn't have faith in the system and police anymore. He make his own justice for the wrong things that he sees.

Considering the tension that is constantly built up in the movie, the state of mind people are in after the alien war they witnessed recently, the team avoided to directly mention the name Batman.

Batman and Superman are the names of the hero, and the whole plot was built up on tension, revenge and anger; where the necessity of mentioning anything heroic wasn't there.

To add weigh on this, the writers even added other names for Batman and Superman as well, like - Caped Crusader, Bat of Gotham, Man vs Alien, Red Cape and others.